# How to add margins between rows of gridview

Tags: css, gridview

I have a gridview and I'm trying to add empty space between each row using CSS.

This doesn't work:

```
#gridview tr{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Neither does this:

```
#gridview td{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Messing with "border-collapse" does nothing as well.

Anyone know how to add spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin will not work in table elements you should use `border` or `padding` like the following snippet

```css
table.grid 
{
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}    

table.grid tr 
{
      border: 0px solid white;
      border-width: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid ">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 1
    </td>  
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 2
    </td>  
  </tr>   
</table>
```

You can use it in `GridView` like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="PetGrid" runat="server" CssClass="grid">
```

Answer (score 1):

use padding:

```
#gridview td{
     padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use padding in th and td,

```
    th, td {
    padding: 15px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
table td {
 border-bottom: solid 20px transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which gridview are you using? try "inspect element" on the grid row and check from which .css class the style is getting inherited. try changing some parameters like **padding/row height** and observe if that works and make the change in the grid's library css or ovverride it with custom class.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#gridview tr{
{

  height: 18px;text-align: left;font-weight: bold;color:white;padding: 5px 6px 2px;border-bottom: 2px solid #666666;white-space: nowrap;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In specifications `margin` are ignored for table cells: [Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout)

Try to use `padding`

```
#gridview td{
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```